# Align list item images to center in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm learning web development with responsive design(still a noob) so please go easy! I will try to be as thorough as possible but please let me know if you need more information!

So I'm trying to design a page which has jquery hover effects on images. You would think I'm having trouble in the JS but my problem is much simpler which makes it frustrating like hell. I want my images to align in the center while they're aligned to the extreme left. the image boxes are li's and I've tried to add them to a div and align the div to the center.

Please note that I also need it to be responsive so can't simply add a margin or padding.

Following is my html body:

```
<body>
<div class="body">

   <div> <img src="images/logo.png" class="image"></div>

            <div class="imgs">
                <ul id="da-thumbs" class="da-thumbs">
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/502538-Natalie-Justin-Cleaning">
                            <img src="images/7.jpg" />
                            <div><span>Natalie & Justin Cleaning by Justin Younger</span></div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/501695-Cornwall-Map">
                            <img src="images/9.jpg" />
                            <div><span>Cornwall Map by Katharina Maria Zimmermann</span></div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
</div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                $(' #da-thumbs > li ').each( function() { $(this).hoverdir({
                    hoverDelay : 75
                }); } );

            });
        </script>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    animation-name: colorChange;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    text-align: center;
}

@keyframes colorChange {
    0% {
        background: #4BB4BF;    
    }
    20% {
        background: #306F7A;    
    }
    40% {
        background: #207DFF;    
    }
    60% {
        background: #1B98E0;    
    }
    80% {
        background: #7EA0E0;    
    }
    100% {
        background: #4BB4BF;    
    }


}

.button {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
}



.da-thumbs {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 0;

}
.da-thumbs li {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.da-thumbs li a,
.da-thumbs li a img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.da-thumbs li a {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.da-thumbs li a div {
    position: absolute;
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(75,75,75,0.7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.da-thumbs li a div span {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 40px 20px 20px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 -10px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}





<!-- Demo content here --> 





*,
*:after,
*:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Clearfix hack by Nicolas Gallagher: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

/* General Demo Style */
body{
    font-family: Cambria, Palatino, "Palatino Linotype", "Palatino LT STD", Georgia, serif;

    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;

}
a{
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 750px;
}
.clr{
    clear: both;
    padding: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.image {
 max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}

.imgs {margin: 0 auto;
align: center;
}
```

Please give your thoughts on how I can align these elements?

Fiddle Case: 
https://jsfiddle.net/eqyfm41r/3/

Comment: Are you trying to vertically align the images in the center while horizontally aligning them to the left?

Comment: No I want to horizontally align them to the left. They should be responsive so if the screen width is short enough, the 2nd image should move below the first one.

Comment: " I want my images to align in the center while they're aligned to the extreme left." Then what do you mean by this?

Comment: I mean to say that right now they are aligned to the extreme left. I want them aligned in the center! Sorry for the confusion :/

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of your case?

Comment: you should at least be able to make a visual description of what you want to achieve

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/eqyfm41r/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edited code:

```
.da-thumbs li {
   display:inline-block;
   width:46%;
   margin: 5px;
   padding: 8px;
   position: relative;
}
.da-thumbs li img{
   box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/1zq95tzp/

You were floating the li's for one thing, also you want to add the box shadows to the images, not the li. The reason for this is that the li is going to be larger than the image, so the box shadow will appear far away from the edges of the actual image. As the screen shrinks, the images will stack. You may need to eventually give the images this styling:

```
max-width:100%;
```

so that they don't go off the page at phone width (I didn't look at the size of the images). Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seemed to work. Although I didn't actually use your css because I had some hover effects which in turn had to be changed for it to work. So I simply deleted the float property which seemed to be the problem. Deleting it worked just fine as I was aligning my div to center in the 'imgs' property! 

Thanks a bunch again! Please upvote this question if you think it may help someone else.

Comment: Will do! Glad I could help. Please upvote my answer if you think that may help someone else, too :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do:

```
margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
```

? This would be responsive, it's not a fixed margin.

Comment: Hi. In the css, if you see the last 'imgs' class definition, you will see that I have used margin: 0 auto. That implements your solution but it does not works. Even tried to use !important with it to make sure no other property anywhere else is over ruling it :/

Comment: I think it is because of imgs' parent element(li,ul or div) is aligned to left and has no 100% width.

Comment: you were right. I had a floating property set to left in the li element. deleted it and the images aligned to center! Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Have a nice day. :) <3